# Can I use LIKE into REPLACE command

Tags: mysql, sql

I have varchar column in MySQL database and it's like:

```
| col |
| --- |
| "0" abc12, "40" abc34, "80" abc56 |
| "90" def34, "113" def56, "256" def78 |
```

I would like to replace all numbers between "" (with "") with empty value, so I need result like this:

```
| col | res |
| --- | --- |
| "0" abc12, "40" abc34, "80" abc56 | abc12, abc34, abc56 |
| "90" def34, "113" def56, "256" def78 | def34, def56, def78 |
```

Comment: If you're using MySQL 8.x you can use `REGEXP_REPLACE()`

Comment: MYSQL 8.x would look like: `SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(yourcolumn, '("[0-9]*")', '') FROM yourtable;` Older versions... this gets ugly.

Answer (score 0):

If you use MySQL 8.0, you can use [REGEXP_REPLACE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace).

If you use an older version of MySQL, the easiest solution is to fetch the string into your client app, perform the string substitutions you need, and UPDATE the string back into the database.

No, there's no way to use LIKE with replace.